# Does Turkish Airline transfers baggage

Tags: luggage, connecting-flights, turkish-airlines

I am traveling for the first time to a different country with Turkish Airlines.
I have a flight from New Delhi to Bordeaux,France with layover at Istanbul.
So will the baggage be transferred by them, or I will need to collect my baggage and get to the other flight?
Both the flights are same i.e, Turkish Airlines.

Comment: You bought the whole flight from New Delhi to Bordeaux as one ticket, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you bought the flight in one ticket, the bags will be transferred automatically for the layover in Istanbul, Turkey.

Even if airlines are different, if you bought it in one ticket, they will connect.

However, if you purchased two tickets, you likely have to go out and recheck the bags. But I had a different experience in KLIA airport. I was allowed to go to transfer desk airside and they was able to connect my luggage through onward flight, without any issues and no fees was collected from me.

Comment: Hey! Anish thanks for your answer, but what if the airlines are different??